# Google spreadsheets conditional formatting - Highlight cell if value higher than

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, conditional-formatting

I have data as such:

```
Avg. Cost   Current Price
$0.44   $0.45
$2.67   $2.35
$0.37   $0.35
$0.39   $0.40
$4.20   $4.30
$0.57   $0.64
```

I'm trying to highlight cells in the 'Current Price' column if the value is higher than the corresponding value from the 'Avg. Cost' column. In the above example, $0.45, $0.40, $4.30, and $0.64 in the 'Current Price' column will be highlighted.

I'm trying to perform this on Google sheets.

Thank you

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I challenged to think of a sample conditional format rule as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to give the highlight using the conditional formatting of Google Spreadsheet.
- In your situation, when the value of the column "B" is more than the value of the column "A", you want to give the highlight for the column "B".

#### Sample conditional format rule:

In this case, how about using `=B2 > A2` as the custom function as follows?

[image]

- In this case, I think that the range can also use `B2:B`.